# Azure web role slower after upgrade

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, syncfusion

I have a web role in azure that is using  [syncfusion docToPdf](http://mvc.syncfusion.com/demos/reporting/pdf/importandexport/doctopdf) to convert word documents to pdf.

If I publish this role using a full deployment, converting a doc is fast, <500ms.

But after a update deployment, it's unusable slow, >5s every time.

If I reimage the instance it will be fast again, until I do a new deployment update.

If I reboot the slow instance it has no effect.

For all other functionality in the role there is no performance difference between full deployment and upgrade deployment.

I do not understand why this is happening or where to start to fix it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this happened because of Application Insights, for some reasons it made word to pdf 10 times slower.

When we modified applicationinsights.config and replaced [All Namespaces] with only our own namespaces syncfusion started running smoothly again

Answer (score 0):

Windows Azure cloud service take some amount of time to initiate the service while accessing it first time, immediately after update deployment. This is due to the cloud service stops from the server when the service is idle for a certain amount of time, while updating the cloud service. Whereas the service remains running immediately after full deployment, hence it doesn’t require to restart service. Please refer the below blog for further details

http://wp.sjkp.dk/windows-azure-websites-and-cloud-services-slow-on-first-request

Comment: Thanks, but its not only slower the first time, but all the time after  an upgrade.